# Get multiple FeatureInfo from multiple WMS layers stacked on top of each other

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wms, getfeatureinfo

I have two layers of WMS layers stacked on top of each other and each contains its own `feature` information. Upper layer has style=line and bottom layer has style=color, and some lines of the upper layer will cover the features of the layer below, like this:

[image]

Each color of the layer below corresponds to a separate feature (skin color = `"features":[{"type":1...`, grey = `"features":[{"type":2...`, red = `"features":[{"type":3...`). I want when I click on the feature of the upper layer, it will show the `FeatureInfo` of the upper layer and three `FeatureInfo` of the layer below to table and show marker number in `feature` of below layer, maybe look like this:

[image]

How do i get the information of the lower layers that are in the area feature of the upper layer?

Relevant existing code:

**Add layer to map**:

```
//below layer
var belowLayer= new ol.layer.Image({
            view: new ol.View({
            projection: 'EPSG:4326'
            }),
            source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost:8081/geoserver/dbpgis/wms',
            params: {LAYERS: 'dbpgis:belowlayer', 'TILED': true},
            serverType: 'geoserver',
            ratio: 1,
            }),
            visible: true,
            title: 'below'
        });
        map.addLayer(belowLayer)

       //upper layer
        var view = new ol.View({
            projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        });
        var source = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost:8081/geoserver/dbpgis/wms',
            params: {LAYERS: 'dbpgis:upperlayer', 'TILED': true},
            serverType: 'geoserver',
            ratio: 1,
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
        });
        var upperLayer= new ol.layer.Image({
            view: view,
            source: source,
            // minZoom: 17,
            visible: true,
            title: 'upper',
        });
        map.addLayer(upperLayer);
```

**getFeatureInfo:**

```
//get featureinfo for upper layer
var content = document.getElementById('info');     
        map.on('click', function (evt) {
            overlayPopup.hide();
            content.innerHTML = '';
            var viewResolution = mapView.getResolution();
            var url = source.getFeatureInfoUrl(
                evt.coordinate,
                viewResolution,
                'EPSG:3857',
                {
                    'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
                    'propertyName': 'feature_upper' 
                },
            );
            if (url) {
                $.getJSON(url, function(data){
                    var feature = data.features[0];
                    var props = feature.properties;
                    content.innerHTML = "<h5>Upper layer : </h5><p>" + props.feature_upper +"</p>"
                                        
                    // overlayPopup.show(content.innerHTML);
                    // console.log(props);
                })
            }else{
                alert('error');
            }
            // console.log(url);
        });  

        //get featureinfo of below layer
        var dataBelow = document.getElementById('info_qpk');
        map.on('click', function(evt){
            dataBelow .innerHTML = '';
            viewData = map.getView();
            var url = belowLayer.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
            evt.coordinate,
            viewData.getResolution(),
            'EPSG:3857',
            {
            'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
            'propertyName':'feature_type_1,...'
            },
            );
            // console.log(url);
            if(url){
            $.getJSON(url, function(data){
                var feature = data.features[0];
                var props = feature.properties;
                dataQPK.innerHTML = "<h5>Below layer : </h5><p>" + props.feature_type_1+ "</p>" + "<hr>"+...
                // overlayPopup.show(dataBelow.innerHTML);
            });
            }
        })
```

Here is my code,  this only get data info at click position.

Comment: Are all the WMS layers from the same service?  If so certainly doable with WMS GetFeatureInfo request, you need to list all the layers that make up the GetMap request (comma separated list in LAYERS), then for all the layers you want to query  you need to list them in the QUERY_LAYERS parameter.

Comment: @nmtoken Yes, all the WMS layer  from GeoServer. But  currently only get the farture information at the mouse click position. I want to get information of the lower layers in the feature area of the upper layer

Comment: By default GetFeatureInfo only works on a point location in the map image, GeoServer offers a 'vendor option' `buffer` with width in pixels, so you may be able to get feature information beyond your clicked point.

Comment: @nmtoken can it get information of the below layer features `(skin color = "features":[{"type":1..., grey = "features":[{"type":2..., red = "features":[{"type":3...)` in the feature area of the upper layer?

Comment: Stop abusing getFeatureInfo and learn how WFS works - this is what it was designed for

Comment: There's also 'vendor option' `cql_filter` where you can specify geometry, see https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#wms-vendor-parameters and https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/ecql_reference.html#filter-ecql-reference

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge about Openlayers and GeoServer. I would be very grateful if someone could give me a simple example.

Comment: @IanTurton  I cannot switch from using WMS to WFS for the specific layer, because the polygons are too many and each one really big and complex.

Comment: But using WFS to make this query is the only thing that will work for you. No need to fetch the whole layer or the geometries at all

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Geoserver in question, why not create a [layer group](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/webadmin/layergroups.html#layer-groups) from both layers, and send the getFeatureInfo request to the layer group?

To quote [the documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo),

> Note: If you are sending a GetFeatureInfo request against a layergroup, all the layers in that layergroup must be set as “Queryable” to get a result (See [WMS Settings on Layers page](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/webadmin/layers.html#data-webadmin-layers))

Response will be a dictionary with features from both layers at the particular location. You only need to parse them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my two layers contain different columns of data so when grouping the layer i can't query the `propertyName` I want because they are different. And this only get data info at click position. How do i click on the feature area of the upper layer but still get the features of the lower layer that are in that area? Thanks you a lot again.

Comment: No need to create a group layer, you can query separate layers in a single GetFeatureInfo request